# Is it possible to write a query to find maximum records without a JOIN and without ORDER BY?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**UPDATED - QUESTION**

Is there a more **more compact** way to write a query that selects maximum records from a table, other than using a self-join?

An example would be a table of events that might have the following schema:

```
   EventID | EventType | Timestamp | Description
-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------
   INT     | VARCHAR   | INT       | VARCHAR
```

And might contain multiple records for each type of event. Let's say:

```
     1     |    A      |  100000   | 'First Event'
     2     |    A      |  100005   | 'Second Event'
     3     |    B      |  100009   | 'Third Event'
     4     |    A      |  100009   | 'Fourth Event'
     5     |    B      |  100010   | 'Fifth Event'
     6     |    B      |  100030   | 'Sixth Event'
     7     |    A      |  100030   | ' ... '
     8     |    C      |  100030   | ' ... '
     9     |    C      |  100050   | ' ... '
```

And let's say I'd like to know what were the most recent events of each type - which would be Events #6, #7 and #9. Then I would have to write a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT EventID
     , EventType
     , Timestamp
     , Description
  FROM EventsTable T
 INNER JOIN (SELECT EventType
                  , MAX(Timestamp) 
               FROM EventsTable TInner
              GROUP BY EventType) TSelf
         ON T.Timestamp = TSelf.Timestamp
         AND T.EventType = TSelf.EventType
```

So the question boils down to: **Is there a more compact way to express the same query, ideally without having to resort to a JOIN**?

Comment: Don't ask performance questions without stating RDBMS. It is meaningless. SQL is declarative. How it is optimised is implementation dependant. SQL Server for example could use a [“Segment Top” Query Optimisation](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/the-segment-top-query-optimisation.aspx) and the execution plan not contain a self join at all.

Comment: @MartinSmith - good point. Updated the question tags

Comment: So what execution plan do you actually get for that query in SQL Server?

Comment: @MartinSmith - it's not about performance as much as expressiveness. I'd like to know if it's possible to express this query without a sub-query, and without ORDER BY

Comment: Actually just noticed that you are only selecting 1 event type. `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * FROM EventsTable WHERE EventType ='B' ORDER BY Timestamp DESC` would likely be the best performing option in SQL Server. No idea why you are trying to avoid an `ORDER BY`. Seems arbitrary to me.

Comment: BTW you **can** use `ORDER BY` in a sub query as long as it is in conjunction with `TOP`. The `ORDER BY` defines the `TOP` not the presentation order of rows.

Comment: @MartinSmith - That's good to know!  But what about if I want the most recent of each type?

Comment: Then this is a [greatest n per group query](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/departments/Optimizing-TOP-N-Per-Group-Queries-103663). You can either self join on an aggregate as per your question. `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1` or use `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25433/discussion-between-miky-dinescu-and-martin-smith)

Comment: That's my stack overflowing finished for now anyway. Got something else to do!

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
SELECT EventID, EventType, Timestamp, Description
FROM EventsTable
WHERE EventType = 'B' AND 
      Timestamp = (SELECT max(Timestamp) FROM EventsTable WHERE EventType = 'B');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EventID, EventType, Timestamp, Description
FROM EventsTable T
WHERE T.EventType = 'B'
ORDER BY Timestamp
LIMIT 1
```

should do the trick (For DBMS that supports LIMIT).

Comment: Good answer if the DBMS support LIMIT.  As the question was just tagged "sql" you might want to add a qualifier to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Didn't realize that you just need one row to be returned. Use Common Table Expression to achieve the desired result. Simple and Cleaner.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT EventID, 
           EventType, 
           Timestamp,
           Description
    FROM EventsTable 
    WHERE EventType = 'B'
)

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CTE 
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
```

Comment: This is not any more compact that the query I gave as example.. You're replacing a query+subquery with a CTE

Comment: Right, though one of the ways without a JOIN. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use order by use this:

```
SELECT * FROM EventsTable WHERE EventType = 'B' AND
Timestamp = (SELECT Max(Timestamp) FROM EventsTable WHERE EventType = 'B');
```

If order by is ok:

Mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM EventsTable WHERE EventType = 'B' ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Sql Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EventsTable WHERE EventType = 'B' ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
```

Plz see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c161/16/0).